# CancellationToken: How to get context info when delegate is called?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using HttpResponse.ClientDisconnectedToken which is a CancellationToken. I have registered an Action method in a CancellationToken (using the CancellationToken.Register() method). When the Action method gets fired, how can I find out what triggered the event?

Comment: What do you mean by `how can I find out what triggered the event?`. From [MSDN for HttpResponse.ClientDisconnectedToken](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpresponse.clientdisconnectedtoken(v=vs.110).aspx) `Gets a CancellationToken object that is tripped when the client disconnects`. So callback was triggered because client got disconnected.

Comment: Right, but I'm trying to find out what caused the client to get disconnected. I figured if I knew what called the action method I created that may provide more info.

Comment: Ah I see. I would encourage you to check [ClientDisconnectedToken](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/HttpResponse.cs,530aaae8d67db0f0) source code, and if you follow along eventually you will end up [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Hosting/IISUnsafeMethods.cs,91a5d5566c500c50). Whatever value gets returned from this method for `pfIsClientConnected` parameter, will decide whether cancellation token is cancelled or not `new CancellationTokenHelper(canceled: !isClientConnected)`.

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: _"I'm trying to find out what caused the client to get disconnected"_ -- "caused" in what way do you mean? The client could be disconnected because someone tripped over a network cable and yanked it out. I assume you don't expect to be notified of that sort of cause. So, what kind of "cause" do you expect to identify? Please provide a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you're trying to do and what you've done to try to solve the problem.